# Can't find the entrance point at procedure clEnqueueCopyBufferRect at dll OpenCL.dll

Tags: opencl, emgucv

I'm getting a problem with a project developed in C# with Emgu CV.

When I try tu run my program in one of my machines it works very well but, when i try to run at other machine (mine too) if doesnt work and show this error:

Can't find the entrance point at procedure clEnqueueCopyBufferRect at dll OpenCL.dll

This error only occurs in one machine.

Note: When i run the examples of EmguCV i get the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

clEnqueueCopyBufferRect is OpenCL 1.1 API function. Does your machine has OpenCL 1.1 support?

Comment: I have the OpenCL.dll in the solution's folder & i have an NVidia graphics Card so i have cuda & OpenCL libraries on my machine.

Comment: My advice is use OpenCL.dll, provided with your driver. Find it & set path to it in linker settings.

Comment: Try to check the presence of clEnqueueCopyBufferRect symbol in your dll. Dependency Walker (http://dependencywalker.com) can do this.